# Android Studio - No Activity Templates available

Tags: android-studio, code-templates

I want to create a new Preferences Screen using the SettingsActivity template. All the websites I looked at gave me these steps:

- Right click on the Package name
- Select "New" from the menu and select "Activity" from the list of options
- Studio will then show a list of Activity templates, one of which will be SettingsActivity

I do not get any such thing in the "New" menu options. All I have are Java Class, Android Resource File and Directory, File, Package, Image Asset, Android Component, package-info.java, HTML file.

When I select Android Component, a dialog box appears allowing me to choose between Activity, Fragment, Application, Service etc., and that is it.

I have Android Studio version 1.0.2 and from folders I see in (...)Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities I do have the SettingsActivity template.

How do I create a new Activity from any of these templates?

EDIT:
I am not using Gradle.

Here is the screenshot of the menu I get.
[image: Screenshot of the right-click menu]

Comment: Do you have any errors with your gradle sync ?

Comment: I am not using Gradle. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it appears that this isn't being recognized by Android Studio as an Android project.  So the wizard isn't showing Android artifacts.  How did you create the project?  Also, if I may ask, why did you decide not to use Gradle?

Comment: I was using Eclipse and only recently switched to Studio. I imported the source using SVN. It is compiling, installing and debugging just fine so I didn't think Gradle was necessary just yet. If it is running the project on the device through ADB, it should be recognized as an Android project right?

Answer (score 2):

The wizards are sensitive to the cursor position and selection.  Click on the package name under "src/main/java" first.  Then right click.  You should see the following.  If not, can you post the image that you do see?

[image]